# Wordpress CSS ruining custom pages

Tags: css, wordpress

I created a real estate search page in PHP.  I then created a custom page template in WordPress and added it to the site. http://geekoutaustin.com/homesearch/

I created everything mostly sticking to Bootstrap to avoid conflicts but as you can see the WordPress CSS has changed everything and looks terrible.

Is there an easy fix to this or do I have to rename everything and give it new CSS?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscores the "cascade" part of CSS.

Order of CSS on file and loading might help, but that is wonky and not reliable.

Use of more direct selection and/or use of !important declaration might bail you out.  Alo not perfect.

A better solution is to wrap the page in a high level id or class (ID better IMO). Everything inside the aforementioned CSS id will then get direct/compound selection. This pattern allows explicit correction for the page ONLY if done correctly.  This could be duct-tape over masking tape, make a good choice.

There is a lot fo potential, here's a low level primer:

#some-id .some-class has higher priority over .some-class
#some-id .some-class div has higher priority over .some-class div

There are MANY More solutions - I am suggesting a "get it done" approach that is not all tech debt or a week lost.

Possibly split off the CSS for the page and only load as needed.

Otherwise, re-do.